# Exporting Amazon Alexa Slots and Intents

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

I've not found any documentation for doing this? Are there methods for importing and exporting Intents and Slots. I cannot find any hint on the front end.

Comment: So far there is no option to export it. You have to manually copy it

Comment: Now you are able to upload a JSON file in the new Beta Builder web app that defines the entire Interaction Model,  which in my opinion is a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

Now it's really easy. 
You can use the JSON Editor that's found in the left menu. There is a key for intents and types, you can copy it and then paste it to another skill's JSON Editor.

[image]